# rspec how to test call to specific method in external class

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I've got a method in a game class...

```
def drawgrid
  @board.draw
end
```

I want to write a test that verifies that drawgrid calls @board.draw

My current test looks like this....

```
  describe 'drawgrid method' do
    it 'should call @board.drawgrid' do

      @game.drawgrid.should be_true

      @game.drawgrid
    end
  end
```

Is this the best/ideal way to write this? Is there a better way?

Am I doing this right?

This seems nebulous to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use should_receive for this:

```
@board.should_receive(:draw)
```